# How do I inject HttpContext to HttpContextBase by Spring.Net config

Tags: spring.net

I have a class like this:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(HttpContextBase httpContext) { }
}
```

I want to inject HttpContext to this class by Spring.net config.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using spring.net expression property.

Comment: Nice you've solved it for yourself! Could you please, extend your answer with more details? If you think it could help others